# How to get and compare existing table names with newly created table's name (PHP5)?

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a simple code which is supposed to check if the entry field is empty or not and if it is not empty, content that is entered in that field should be the name of the newly created database TABLE. But I'm having a problem with the part where the code needs to check if the table with that name already exists or not. This is what I have so far:

```
include 'conn.php';

$entry_name = $_POST['entry_name'];

// Check if the field is empty

if(empty($_POST['entry_name'])) {
    echo "Please, fill the name field!";  
}

// If the field is full
else {
    // Check for the duplicated table names 

    $result = mysql_query(**???**);
    if($result == $entry_name) {
        die("Entry with that name already exists, choose a different name!");
    }

    // If there are no tables with entered name, create the new table
    else {
        $entry_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['entry_name']);
        mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `" . $entry_name . "` ( first VARCHAR(30), second VARCHAR(30))");

        echo "$entry_name created successfully!";
    }

}
```

The part with the question marks is where I don't know what exactly to do.

Comment: Use `SHOW TABLES` and iterate through the result array. Your code is also ripe for the picking in terms of being vunerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Stop. Use PDO/MySQLi, and then re-ask the question; `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. (actually, reasking would be too far. but seriously, *drop ext/mysql functions if you're using PHP5*)

Comment: Which version of PHP5. Pretty much *all* PHP these days is PHP5, but there are big differences between PHP 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, etc.

Comment: Is my answer resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do that is to query [information schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/schemata-table.html) DB. It contains all information about existing DBs and tables. But mysql 5 only.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `TABLES` 
WHERE  `TABLE_SCHEMA` =  'your_database_name'
AND  `TABLE_NAME` =  'your_table_name'
```

change your `$result = mysql_query(**???**);` to

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM  `TABLES` WHERE  `TABLE_SCHEMA` =  "your_database_name" AND  `TABLE_NAME` =  "'. $entry_name .'");
```

and than

```
if (mysql_numrows($result) !== 0)
```

don't forget to change `your_database_name` to **your** database name
Oh, and don't forget to sanitize your $entry_name. [mysql_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php)

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5 but can you please make an example of this code inside of my code? I get it in theory, but since I'm still a PHP beginner, I'm having problems with inserting that in my code, I always get some syntax errors in my IDE.

Comment: ext/mysql is deprecated. using it is a horrible idea for php5

Comment: I know it's deprecated and it was mentioned before. But **Jay Query** used it. And it will be hometask to him to rewrite project to mysqli. But if i write sample with mysqli it wan't work at all without changing all prev. code.

Comment: Good new here is that we can just change mysql to mysqli in my sample and nothing changes.

Comment: Where exactly should I put "if (mysql_numrows($result) !== 0)"? no matter where I put it, I always get "Warning: mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in that line" after submitting my entry.

Comment: You ned just change your two lines  
    `$result = mysql_query(**???**);`
    `if($result == $entry_name) {`
to my two
if you still getting that error it means you(my) query ins't works correctly. You need to test mysql_error() to check what's wrong.